# I want to remove the thumbnail image in all portfolio pages, and replace it with static image

Tags: wordpress, image, header, thumbnails, elementor

I'm using Wordpress/Elementor, and I have a problem in my portfolio page.

I want each project page, not to show the “Thumbnail” image in th header, because it takes the image and enlarge it, which makes unreadable, and also it affects the visibility of the project’s title. so it would be much better of the header, only contains the project title, and that’s it, just like how the title of “About’ page is shown, ( please see screenshots ) , just the title ” About”, and that darkened background, I want the same thing the portfolio project pages do, show only the title of the project and that’s it, even the caption of the project is unwanted.

So the idea is : each portfolio project page, show only the title of the project in the header, with the same background in “About” page, without the caption text, because it’s a duplicate.

Link the project sample which contains the issue : https://hilaoui.com/portfolio/project-page/

Link to the example of the “About” page header : https://hilaoui.com/about/

[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGLJZ.png)

[Screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w88Q.png)
Thank you so much for your help.